# How can we split the DataLoader object into train and test?

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-datasets, object-detection-api, dataloader

I have been following below document from tensorflow-lite model maker object detection api.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection

Following the documentation in the advance usage section, I have tried to import my custom dataset by uploading those in the google drive.

Both of the image files and the annotation files I have been able to find from openimage dataset.

https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/download.html

Below line I am able to run without issue.

object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(image_loc, annotations_loc, label_map={1: "person", 2: "notperson"})

Image_loc contains images in .jpg format and annotation_loc contains data in pascal voc xml format.

Unfortunately the return object of the above line is of type DataLoader.

How may I divides the dataloader output in train and test and run the different models starting with **efficientdet-lite0** on those data?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `annotation_filenames` parameter in `from_pascal_voc` function ([api](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector/DataLoader#from_pascal_voc))to specify which annotations are used for training / validation.